# Analytic continuation and convergence of generating function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

For a real sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ I am considering the generating function $s(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ and by some calculations I find that it has a representation $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ where $f$ has poles ${z_1,z_2,...}$ on the real line with $0< z_1< z_2<...$ and $f$ is analytic for $|z|<|z_1|$.
Now I know that since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is analytic within its radius of convergence and $f$ is analytic for $|z|<|z_1|$ they both coincide within the radius of convergence of the series $s$ by uniqueness of analytic continuations.

But can I also conclude that the radius of convergence of $s$ is just $|z_1|$ since if it were smaller there would be a pole somewhere in the disk $|z|<|z_1|$ which would contradict the equality with $f$ and the fact that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: What exactly does "$s$ has a representation $f$" mean?

Comment: If $s(z)$ is analytic for all $|z| < |z_1|$ then the power series has radius of convergence  $R$ which is at least $|z_1|$.  If you also know it has a pole at $z_1$ then the radius of convergence is less than or equal to $|z_1|$.  Thus $R = |z_1|$. Does that help?